# Empty visual tree in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-tree, visualtreehelper

I just want to see visual elements of controls, and to do it I created a really basic window which contains two labels and button. The problem is that I can't see any visual as I expected either in VisualTreeHelper or visual studio's tool named "WPF Tree Visualizer".

[Current project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUeM9.png)

The weird part is that it works in my another project.

[Another project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd2Df.png)

What may cause of this? Why it doesn't work as in my other project?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are calling the code in the constructor. Try calling the same code in the window loaded event and you should see a difference.

Comment: Well, I didn't realize that I should use Visual Tree structure in loaded event. It works not, thanks for the answer

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/object-lifetime-events?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) gives a good explanation. Basically, the visual tree has not been created yet when the constructor is called.